# Web Test plugin not being used in Load Test

Tags: performance, visual-studio, load-testing

I have a web test which uses a web test plugin to add a header (Authorization Token) to each request. This works fine when running the web test and saves me from having to add it to every request.

When I perform a load test using the web test, the headers are not being included, or included incorrectly as the authorization fails for each request. Note that load tests are successful if I actually add the authorization requests to each request in a web test (not using the plugin).

Do I need to create a separate load test plugin, or should this be working correctly? Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The webtest plugin should be sufficient. Try a loadtest with constant load of one virtual user and run time enough for three executions. See what happens. Look in the web test logs of failed executions and see which pass and which fail.

Comment: It worked correctly after a reboot. Thanks for the help.